# SSRS Mail setup: hosted exchange

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have an issue configuring reporting services to work with email subscriptions from a hosted exchange server. I have entered the desired email address and SMTP server details in the reporting services configuration manager.

That's about as far as I've gone - I'm struggling with next steps to be honest as we don't have an exchange server on premises.

Answer (score 0):

I have sql2012 and there are some smtp configuration settings in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\rsreportserver.config

I haven't tried it myself, but i don't see why it shouldn't work. restart SSRS after changing the configuration.